# NumPy shape attribute giving incomplete output

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

My `numPy array` looks as below:

```
 a3 = np.array(
          [[[1, 2.0, 3.3],
            [4, 5, 6, 5],
            [7, 8, 9]],
           
           [[10, 11, 12],
            [13, 14, 15],
           [13, 14, 15]]],
         dtype=object)
```

Now, I am trying to print the shape as below:
`print(a3.shape)`

I am getting output `(2, 3)`

As per my understanding the output should be `(2, 3, 3).`

Comment: When one attribute of an array, such as the shape is not what you expect, look at the array in more detail.  This is a small enough one that you can print it directly.  Why did you include the `dtype=object`?  Did you initially get a `ragged array` warning?  Yes that does suggest using `object` dtype.  But that doesn't fix the shape!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding since you put an unequal length list `[4, 5, 6, 5]` in there and use `dtype=object`, they are saved as lists. Printing them will get you:

```
print(a3)
> [[list([1, 2.0, 3.3]) list([4, 5, 6, 5]) list([7, 8, 9])]
   [list([10, 11, 12]) list([13, 14, 15]) list([13, 14, 15])]]
```

Or:

```
print(type(a3[0][0]))
> <class 'list'>
```

So numpy gives you the shape of the array containing these lists. If you remove the extra element it is saved as a proper ndarray containing numbers and gives you `(2, 3, 3)` as expected.